# Issue regarding accept() in socket server client programming in C (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, client-server

I have written a server and client program using socket in C in Linux.

Codes are given below:

Server Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
struct sockaddr_in server , client;
char client_message[2000];

//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}
puts("Socket created");

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

//Bind
if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    //print the error message
    perror("bind failed. Error");
    return 1;
}
puts("bind done");

//Listen
listen(socket_desc , 3);

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

//accept connection from an incoming client
client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
if (client_sock < 0)
{
    perror("accept failed");
    return 1;
 }
puts("Connection accepted");
  close(client_sock);
  puts("I am at While loop");
  while(1)
    {
    }
return 0;
}
```

Client Code:

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in server;
char message[1000] , server_reply[2000];

//Create socket
sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (sock == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}
puts("Socket created");

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

//Connect to remote server
if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    perror("connect failed. Error");
    return 1;
}

puts("Connected\n");
close(sock);
while(1);
return 0;
}
```

when I run server code and then client code it works fine but when I terminate client code run it again (server code executed once only) it automatically connects to server without accept being called by server.

I don't want client to get connected until server calls  accept() to connect with client.

I just want client to wait or give some timeout until server calls accept() to establish connection between them.

Output I am getting is below :

Server Output:

```
root@beaglebone:/home/Saad/test# ./server_test
Socket created                                                      
bind done                              
Waiting for incoming connections...
Connection accepted
I am at While loop
```

Client Output:

```
root@beaglebone:/home/Saad/test# ./client_test     
Socket created                         
Connected                                                           

^C                                                   
root@beaglebone:/home/Saad/test# ./client_test
Socket created                                              
Connected
```

I don't know why this is happening and how to resolve it.

UPDATE:

I have tried the answer below after some edits in client code  I am facing same problem.

Client code:

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
   char buf[1];
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in server;
char message[1000] , server_reply[2000];
int ret;

//Create socket
sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (sock == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}
puts("Socket created");

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.2");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

//Connect to remote server
ret = connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));
if (ret < 0)
{
    perror("connect failed. Error");
    return 1;
}
recv(sock, buf, 1, MSG_WAITFORONE);
printf("%s",buf);
puts("Connected\n");
close(sock);
sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (sock == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}
puts("Socket created");
ret = connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));
if (ret < 0)
{
    perror("connect failed. Error");
    return 1;
}
else
{
 puts("Connected\n");
}
while(1);
return 0;
}
```

Client output:

```
root@beaglebone:/home/Saad/test# ./client_test_1
Socket created
1Connected

Socket created
Connected
```

Comment: Your server accept the first connection and then it loops infiniteely into a while(1). You have to code disconnect and accempt into the loop.

Comment: Guys, run his code. The connect part in the client code does not fail even though the server is in the while loop and does not accept anything (I tested it running multiple, parallel instances of the client).

Comment: @alk You have obviously never heard of the listen backlog queue.

Comment: @EJP: Indeed, I missed that incoming connections might be completed in the queue already.

Comment: @alk Well that's what the question is about.

Comment: If you want to wait, just write code that waits. If the client needs to know when the server has done something, then the server needs to tell the client when it has done something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@EJP explained it well, if you want to fix you issue, use this code:

Client:

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    char buf[1];
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[1000] , server_reply[2000];
    int ret;

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Connect to remote server
    ret = connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    recv(sock, buf, 1, MSG_WAITFORONE);

    puts("Connected\n");
    close(sock);
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>    //write   
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{   
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char client_message[2000];

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    //accept connection from an incoming client
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);

    send(client_sock, "1", 1, 0);
    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connection accepted");
    close(client_sock);
    puts("I am at While loop");
    while(1)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On the client side:
I added a `recv` call on the client side, that blocks until the server actually sends something.

On the server side:
I added a `send` call right after the accept call. That makes sure only clients that have been accepted will continue their code path.

Comment: Why the `MSG_WAITFORONE`? Is there some evidence he wants to go into non-blocking mode afterwards?

Comment: @EJP You're obviously very informed on this subject, I learned a lot reading your answer and comments, please provide a better answer instead of bashing mine. To address your comment in a non passive-aggressive way - this is the quickest example I could come up with that actually solves his problem, I do not know the entire scope of his application so I can't really tell.

Comment: @Ishay Peled thanks for your help,but I haven't got the point why it is working by just adding send and recv to the code, even when I execute client code it blocks on Connect() but why not in my code?

Comment: Saad, to put it simple, when your server calls listen, it actually creates a listening thread and a backlog queue in the kernel that will keep successful TCP connections from clients. Each time a client connects, that thread handles the connection and places the new connection in the backlog. When you call accept, a connection is retrieved from that queue and is made available for your server to process. The most important part to understand here is that accept does not respond directly to a connect request from the server - the kernel does, and it uses the backlog queue as a mediator.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really 'create a listening thread', but the kernel does the connection-completion in the background.

Comment: @IshayPeled I have done some edit in client code and again I am getting same issue. I have updated my question with updated client code

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want client to get connected until server calls accept() to connect with client.

Bad luck, that's not how TCP works. `listen(socket_desc , 3)` creates a *backlog queue*, using the second parameter as a hint as to its length, which will be ignored in this case as it is too small. The purpose of this queue is to hold connections that have been completed by TCP but not yet accepted by the server application. Typical sizes vary from 50 to 500 or more, depending on the platform.

> I just want client to wait or give some timeout until server calls `accept()` to establish connection between them.

Unimplementable. Why do you think you need this?

> I don't know why this is happening and how to resolve it.

You can't resolve it, except by a pointless extra send/recv as per @IshayPeled's answer. It isn't a problem that needs resolving. If you think otherwise please tell us why. Every other TCP application ever written works this way. What's different about yours?

Comment: I have given backlog queue 100 but the result is same.

Comment: Of course the result is the same, except that 100 clients will be able to do what your second client does. I don't understand why you thought it would change.

Comment: If you want it to block, you can call recv on the client side just after you call connect and send something on the server side right after it calls accept. The recv call will block because no data arrives on that socket and will only release once the server sends something on it (which happens right after accept)

Comment: Can you give any reason why client accepts connection with server when accept is not being called?

Comment: @IshayPeled I am not just running these codes to get started with sockets, I have a full application in which I am hiving this problem

Comment: @EJP Sorry, but I am unable to interpret your reason, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Saad, This is the best I can do to help, I provided an answer with a tested workaround for your issue, but even if you don't - I learned a lot from this thread and recommend you look into @EJP's excellent explanation - its all there.

Comment: @SaadRafey Not understanding an answer is different from not getting one. I had already given you the reason in my answer: 'the purpose of this queue is to hold connections that have been completed by TCP but not yet accepted by the server application'. What part of that is unclear and requires elaboration? NB You don't have a 'problem'. This is how TCP is designed to work. If you've misdesigned your application around a non-existent feature you will just have to redesign it. The real question here is where you got your misconception from. Not from any proper documentation, that's for sure.

Comment: @SaadRafey What I am talking about is your unreasonable request above 'Can you give any reason why client accepts connection with server when accept is not being called? ' when I had already given exactly that in my answer, with some detail. If you don't understand an answer, by all means say so, but don't pretend it hasn't been given. NB You haven't answered any of the questions I asked.

Comment: @SaadRafey You can pretend all you like that I haven't answered your question, but I have. It's up there in black and white. Everybody can see it, and everybody else has said so. I repeat. If you don't understand, ask. Don't pretend.